# Difference in result because of quotes

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn scala and was doing an assignment but am unable to figure out the following...

So, the question is to recursively figure out whether parenthesis is balanced or not...recursively.
So here is my a working solution..

```
 def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    def iterate(chars: List[Char], sum:Int):Int = {
       if(chars.isEmpty ||  sum<0) sum 
       else if(chars.head == '(') iterate(chars.tail ,sum+1)
       else if(chars.head == ')') iterate(chars.tail,sum-1)
       else iterate(chars.tail, sum)

    }
    iterate(chars,0) == 0
  }
```

But if change my code to following

```
 def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    def iterate(chars: List[Char], sum:Int):Int = {
       if(chars.isEmpty ||  sum<0) sum 
       else if(chars.head == "(") iterate(chars.tail ,sum+1) //NOTE double quotes 
       else if(chars.head == ")") iterate(chars.tail,sum-1) //NOTE double quotes
       else iterate(chars.tail, sum)

    }
    iterate(chars,0) == 0
  }
```

This always return true...

Why?

```
//test with 
val s1 = ":-)"
println(balance(s1.toList))
```

Comment: If you pay attention to the compiler warnings you might be able to avoid problems like this. When I compile a snippet from the above code, the compiler tells me `warning: comparing values of types Char and String using \`==' will always yield false`, and it gives the line number in question as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chars.head is a Char,'(' is a Char, but "(" is a String, so these two branches will always evalate to false

```
else if(chars.head == "(") iterate(chars.tail ,sum+1) //NOTE double quotes 
else if(chars.head == ")") iterate(chars.tail,sum-1) //NOTE double quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Using match, you'd see an error:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("(")
 required: Char
               case "(" => loop(cs.tail, sum + 1)
                    ^
```

with the corrected code:

```
def balance(cs: Seq[Char]) = {
  def loop(cs: Seq[Char], sum: Int): Int = {
    if (cs.isEmpty || sum < 0) sum
    else {
      val i = cs.head match {
        case '(' => 1
        case ')' => -1
        case _   => 0
      }
      loop(cs.tail, sum + i)
    }
  }
  loop(cs, 0) == 0
}
```